# Change copies to the current register

Tags: key-bindings

I am aware of the fact that a delete or change yanks to the current register.Since I do not want that behaviour I make them yank to the Black hole register with these two lines in vim rc file

```
nnoremap dd "xdd  
nnoremap c "xc
```

Now I do not want `C`to yank to the current register however when I do this

```
nnoremap C "xC
```

I cannot get the same effect and the content which is deleted is stored in the current register.

Comment: I tried first two remaps on my linux machine, it still yanks to current register..  check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-delete-without-putting-text-in-the-register and in general you might want to learn about using vim registers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497958/how-do-i-use-vim-registers

Comment: well if I do "xdd in my editor it yanks to the black hole

Comment: can you check by using `_` instead of `x` in all three remaps? may be something else is the issue here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_` is the blackhole register, not `x`.  You're just storing the text in the `x` register, **and** in the `"` register.

```
nnoremap dd "_dd  
nnoremap c "_c
nnoremap C "_C
```

You should try getting used to the default behavior of the unnamed register.  `ddp` is a very easy way to swap lines, just as `xp` is an easy way to swap characters.  You won't get things like that if you blackhole the change mappings.

Comment: Addendum: If this is something you *really* want to do, I think you should be using `onoremap` for some of those mappings such as `d`.